# news records disappear after a time without clearing the cache

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I'm struggling with a strange behavior.
I use News 8.3.0 and TYPO3 9.5.18. It is a TYPO3 instance with many micro-sites and its own news, which can also be displayed on other pages, depending on the category.

This works for a while but at some point (a few days) no more news are displayed. (List / detail) If I clear all cache it works again. Is such behavior known? Or do you have a hint for troubleshooting?

The extension eventnews is also used and on the page, the plugin is available twice with the action News-> list. Maybe multiple use of the action on the same site is the problem.

Both list-views use the widget n:widget.paginate

Comment: there are two options n existing news is not shown: the archive time is reached or the news is shown already in another place (on the same page). But both would be permananet and not only until cache is cleared. nonetheless I would suspect the later one for a misinterpretation between the many microsites.

Comment: Thank for your comment. But it might be a caching problem. At some point no news are shown like there where no news-records. After clearing the cache everything works fine again

Comment: Which other extensions are installed?

Comment: eventnews, ke_search,vhs,ws_scss

Comment: i have some more information. The news-records disappear in the FE for 1hour and the problem is the table cf_extbase_datamapfactory_datamap. if i truncate the table everything works again.

Comment: I also found a bugreport that matches my problem. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75399 mybe a workaround could be to disable the extbase_datamapfactory_datamap only for tx_news. is this possible?